# How to install mitmproxy certificates in fedora 25 system?

Tags: fedora-25, mitmproxy

I have fedora 25.
I read this article - http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/certinstall.html#certinstall, but information for fedora is not exists.

How to install mitmproxy certificates for fedora 25?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Fedora's Documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/using-shared-system-certificates/#proc_adding-new-certificates):

> To add a certificate in the simple PEM or DER file formats to the list of CAs trusted on the system, copy the certificate file to the `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` directory, for example:
>
> ```
> # cp certificate.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
> # update-ca-trust
> ```

Not sure if it will work for Fedora 25, but that has reached EOL anyways.

Comment: This instructions now also exist in mitmproxy.